# Using a button c++ winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, button, window

I want to add a button to my window and this is its code :

```
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
        L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
        L"Check for update",      // Button text 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
        10,         // x position 
        30,         // y position 
        150,        // Button width
        30,        // Button height
        hWnd,     // Parent window
        NULL,     // No menu.<----------
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
```

Now, i want the window to do something, if the button is pressed, so i found the method:

`UINT IsDlgButtonChecked( HWND hDlg, int  nIDButton );`

OR

```
  HWND hDlg,
  int  nIDFirstButton,
  int  nIDLastButton,
  int  nIDCheckButton
);
```

**Question:** In both methods there is an ID, but I can't find anything about, where to get the ID, so, the lastbuttonid, firstbuttonid, and the button id itself. Also, I know that at the arrow in the code above, where the comment "No menu. <---------" is, there i have to add something like "ID_RADIOBTN1", but i can't find such a constant.
You can just tell me any function that you know and works for you, since i ll take any that works.

Comment: You define the 'replacement' token for `ID_RADIOBTN1` (and other IDs) yourself. Typically, those definitions will be in a header file and look like `#define ID_MYBUTTON1 123`. You then pass those values as the `hMenu` argument. You can use (almost) any values in the range from (about) 10 thru `0x7FFF` (32767) for your buttons. (Low values are used by the system for standard buttons like "OK" and "Cancel".)

Comment: ... or, for a 'purer' C++ system, you could use `constexpr unsigned int ID_MYBUTTON1 = 123;`.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, found something. Sometimes youtube is more explicit than websites.

You have to define a constant, e.g.:
`define ID_Button1 100`

Then just use that id, so write `(HMENU)ID_Button1` as the parameter that you mentioned (next to your "no menu <----------" command.

Comment: No, youtube is not more explicit as official documentation.

Comment: @user2120666 You should read the definition of a website... A website is not a documentation.

Comment: What about you talking???